# Send message to multiple tagged user

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

How to send a message to multiple user by tagging.

```
@bot.command(pass_context=True)
async def ping(ctx, member: discord.Member):
        await bot.send_message(member, "Pong...".format(ctx.message))
```

So above code works perfectly when tagged a single user `?ping @user1` but how to make it work when we tag multiple users `?ping @user1 @user2`.

So is it possible to make it custom message given in channel not in script. example: when we type `?ping @user1 @user2`  bot should ask a message to send, when we add a message it will forward thet message to tagged user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can take a variable number of arguments to a command the same way we would in any other python function.  If we put the message first, and require it to be wrapped in quotes, then we can do all of this in a single command.

```
@bot.command(pass_context=True)
async def ping(ctx, message, *members: discord.Member):
    for member in members:
        await bot.send_message(member, message)
```

Usage:

```
!ping "This is a message" @Demotry @PatrickHaugh
```

EDIT:

If you want to avoid forcing the user to encapsulate their `message` in quotes, you can use [`Clint.wait_for_message`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Client.wait_for_message)

```
@bot.command(pass_context=True)
async def ping(ctx, *members: discord.Member):
    await bot.say("What message would you like to send?")
    message = await bot.wait_for_message(channel=ctx.message.channel, author=ctx.message.author)
    for member in members:
        await bot.send_message(member, message.content)
```

Comment: getting error `in wrapped
    raise CommandInvokeError(e) from e
discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: AttributeError: '<class 'discord.ext.commands.bot.Bot'>' object has no attribute 'wait_from_message'`  I did changed to `await bot.wait_from_message` to `await bot.wait_for_message` but bot sending messge like <discord.message.Message object at 0x00000000>

Comment: That's a good point, you probably want to send `message.content` instead

Answer (score 0):

The `message` class contains a [`mentions`](http://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Message.mentions) attribute that you can iterate over.

```
@bot.command(pass_context=True)
async def ping(ctx):
    for member in ctx.message.mentions:
        await bot.send_message(member, "Pong...".format(ctx.message))
```

Comment: edit:  you missed `@bot.command`  now its telling `discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: AttributeError: 'Message' object has no attribute 'members'`

Comment: Sorry, should be using `mentions` instead of `members`. Fixed now

Comment: Yes worked.. what about my second question is it possible ? example: when we type ?ping @.user1 @.user2 bot should ask a message to send, when we add a message it will forward thet message to tagged user.